# How to get nested aggregations buckets using java high level REST client Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some nested fields, of which I want to calculate all distinct values, for example:

```
"author":{
  "type":"nested",
  "properties":{
    "first_name":{
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
         }
       }
     }
   "last_name":{
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Suppose I need all unique first names, so I am adding an aggregation like this :

```
GET /statementmetadataindex/data/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_authors": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "authors"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_first_names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "authors.first_name.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which returns an aggregation like this:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "distinct_authors" : {
      "doc_count" : 20292,
      "distinct_first_names" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 4761,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 124467,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Charles",
            "doc_count" : 48411
          },
          {
            "key" : "Rudyard",
            "doc_count" : 30954
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I am using Nested aggregation builder in the java code like this :

```
NestedAggregationBuilder uniqueAuthors=AggregationBuilders.nested("distinct_authors", "authors");
TermsAggregationBuilder distinct_first_name= AggregationBuilders.terms("distinct_first_names")
 .field("authors.first_name.keyword").size(size);
uniqueAuthors.subAggregation(distinct_first_name);
```

and I usually get the aggregation like this from the response:

```
Terms distinct_authornames=aggregations.get("distinct_authors");
```

but the buckets that I need are in the sub-aggregation "distinct_first_names" inside "distinct_authors" , so how do I parse the aggregation result to get the unique buckets with the first names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
Nested distinct_authornames=aggregations.get("distinct_authors");
Terms distinct_first_names=distinct_authornames.getAggregations().get("distinct_first_names");

for (Terms.Bucket bucket : distinct_first_names.getBuckets()) 
{
    System.out.println((int) bucket.getDocCount());
    System.out.println(bucket.getKeyAsString());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, I was doing the same thing, turns out I was so engrossed in the new changes that I didn't notice that some(probably need a break)  other part of the code was causing an exception, finally decided to print out the exact exception and realised the problem, and fixed it, the Nested aggregation wasn't the issue to begin with.Anyway thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution, quite long time back , but didn't realise it was working because I kept getting exception , due to some other reason. The following works well :

```
Nested distinct_authorsOuter=aggregations.get("distinct_authors");
            Aggregations distinct_authors_aggs=distinct_authorsOuter.getAggregations();

Terms distinct_firstNames= distinct_authors_aggs.get("distinct_first_names");
```