# Elasticsearch: Find inner hits by nested objects queries

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, time-series

I have a pseudo documents like this:

```
{
    "snapshots": [
        {
            "code":"[id]",
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attribute1": "[Some value]",
            "attribute2": "[Some value]"
        }, {
            "code":"[id]",
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attribute2": "[Some value]"
        }
    ],
    "attributeXYZ":[
        {
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attributeXYZ": "[Some value]"
        },
        {
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attributeXYZ": "[Some value]"
        }
    ],
    "attributeZYX":[
        {
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attributeZYX": "[Some value]"
        },
        {
            "dateFrom": "[Date]",
            "dateTo": "[Date]",
            "attributeZYX": "[Some value]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Fields "snapshots","attributeXYZ","attributeZYX" are nested objects. Is it possible to select inner hits objects from the snapshots (fields snapshots.dateFrom,snapshots.dateTo,snapshots.code) where condition is for example `snapshots.attribute1="Some value" AND attributeXYZ.attributeXYZ="Some value" AND snapshots.dateFrom<attributeXYZ.dateTo AND snapshots.dateTo>attributeXYZ.dateFrom` ? So I want to query across nested objects and date time context must overlay. I am fighting with nested aggregations, but with no success yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To query the nested fields, you need to construct nested queries - suppose in your example the filter is  snapshots.attribute1="Some value" AND attributeXYZ.attributeXYZ="Some value" AND snapshots.dateFromattributeXYZ.dateFrom ?
so you will need to put these three conditions inside a single bool- must query like:

```
  {
    "query":{
      "bool":{
          "must":[
              {<term- query for snapshots.attribute1="Some value">},
              {<nested query having term match query inside for 
                attributeXYZ.attributeXYZ="Some value" >},
              {<nested query having range queries with gte and lte  inside for 
                snapshots.dateFrom<attributeXYZ.dateTo AND 
                snapshots.dateTo>attributeXYZ.dateFrom>}
            ] 
         }
     }
  }
```

If instead you need an OR condition you can put all the Or-ed candidates inside a "should" clause and set the minimum_should_match property of the should clause to '1'.

Coming to the aggregation part, you can take a look at this question- [How to get nested aggregations buckets using java high level REST client Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952209/how-to-get-nested-aggregations-buckets-using-java-high-level-rest-client-elastic)

Comment: Thank you for your time. My question is about last mentioned nested query "nested query having range queries with gte and lte  inside for 
                snapshots.dateFrom<attributeXYZ.dateTo AND 
                snapshots.dateTo>attributeXYZ.dateFrom". Is it even possibe to cross reference nested objects fields? I think something like this not working: {
      "nested": {
       "path": ["snapshots","attributeXYZ"],
       "query": {
        "bool": {
         "filter": {
          "range": {
           "snapshots.dateFrom": { "lt": "attributeXYZ.dateTo" }
          }}}}}}

Comment: No, it isn't - reference - "Lastly, it is not possible to "cross reference" between nested documents. One nested doc cannot "see" another nested doc's properties." (https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch ) - once you have provided the path, you can reference nested elements only under that path( probably because internally Elasticsearch maintains a separate indexes for the nested fields )