# Nested field type will only search as one doc count in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use `AggregationBuilders` to aggregate my document count by its client name since we have multiple clients associated with a single doc. we are using the nested field  `client_name` to index and search for a document.

Here is my data format

```
{
    "id": "5f68c6c80f52a45a0db6d470",
    "name": "Mi Note 10 Lite",
    "brand": {
      "name": "xiaomi"
    },
    "client_name": [
      {
        "name": "client a"
      },
      {
        "name": "client b"
      }
    ]
  }
```

when I'm trying to search with aggregation filter for a client a and b, it will be only return one document count

```
"aggregations": {
      "client a": {
         "doc_count": 1
     },
     "client b": {
         "doc_count": 0
     },
}
```

I am using java API with elastic search 6.3.

here is my query code

```
boolQuery.should(new NestedQueryBuilder(CLIENT_NAME,
                        QueryBuilders
                                .termQuery(CLIENT_NAME + "." + NAME, token),ScoreMode.None));
```

and here is my `AggregationBuilders.filter(k,v);`

should not aggregation bucket return doc count 1 on both bucket or am I missing something?

Comment: please post full aggregation section of your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search result, and search query

**Index Mapping:**

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "client_name": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index Data:

```
{
    "id": "5f68c6c80f52a45a0db6d470",
    "name": "Mi Note 10 Lite",
    "brand": {
        "name": "xiaomi"
    },
    "client_name": [
        {
            "name": "client a"
        },
        {
            "name": "client b"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs": {
        "client": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "client_name"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "client_count": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "client_name.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
"client": {
  "doc_count": 2,
  "client_count": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "client a",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "client b",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**You can refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953731/10348758), to convert the above elasticsearch query to JAVA code.**

Comment: another suggestion, use "keyword" instead of "text" mapping to have the whole string "client a" instead of separate buckets for "client" and "a". you can change or add a multi-field under "name" with the "keyword" type, and aggregate on the "name.keyword" field instead.

Comment: @TomElias Have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out :) And please don't forget to upvote my answer, if you liked it :)